# c# parallelism multiple tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I want to achieve something like :

- Create a bunch of mongo queries
- For each query, get the deserialized mongo data set as a `ObjectA`
- Map all `ObjectA` to a list of `ObjectB` (takes some time given that we're working with several millions objects)
- When the mapping is done, upserts all `ObjectB` (in a loop) to a new mongo db/collection (also takes some time), and start fetching/mapping the next data set with the next query
- if the next mapping is done before the last mongo upsert is finished, wait for it to complete then start writing that data-set to mongo

Now I've been toying around with `Task`, I think it's the way to go but I have a hard time getting how to do this.

Should I run 2 arrays of tasks?

How can I create the "dependency" between a "fetch/map task" and a "write to mongo task"?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can use WaitHandle base class, as ManualResetEvent class object instance, for example

Comment: As I read it you need some sort of synchronization to avoid racing conditions. This makes it impossible to do multithreading as you want to avoid the next object to finish before the previous one is inserted into the new DB? The only thing I can think or right now is doing your mapping with Parallel.for(each) and set the option to retain the order. But the "Upserting" would have to be done in order either way.

Comment: The "Upserting" doesn't require te be done in order, actually. I could do with multithreading but it leads to memory consumption issues, because of the large data set of items I would have to pass to the threads.
@ArturMustafin: I'll look into that, might be a possibility.

Comment: @LaurentH dear stackoverflow user, also, there are breaking changes in Task class from .NET FW 2.0 (3.5) to 4.0 (4.5). there are no static and overloaded function calls in previous verion, as well as WaitFor... overloaded function calls, f.e. tasks.WaitForExecute(); yours faithfully, arturm

Comment: @ArturMustafin Task was only introduced in .NET 4.0. What `Task` are you talking about???

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In BCL Task class was introduced in .NET 2.0

Comment: [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) and the TPL were introduced in .NET 4.0. What Task are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Dataflow http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx

You can create a block for each stage of your process and then chain them together.

1. execute query (TransformBlock)
2. transform response (TransformBlock)
3. upsert (ActionBlock)

then you can post the unique query data to the dataflow in a loop and set the parallelism as needed. e.g. up the parallelism of stage 1 & 2 as long a you aren't having memory issues, but keep stage 3 non-parallel